# Is it a bad practice to deploy same contract multiple time?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js, decentralized-applications

I have developed this application so that I can deploy contracts with same purpose by only clicking a button. Since I am using the same abi and byte code every time, I wonder if it is a bad practice?

This is my dapp.

async function deployContract() {

```
    const abi =[
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "_name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "_symbol",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "_initBaseURI",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "hasRedPill",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "similarity",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "test",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
      }
    ]

    

    const numberContractByteCode =  "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"

    const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, numberContractByteCode, signer)

    const numberContract = await factory.deploy("1","2","3");

    const transactionReceipt = await numberContract.deployTransaction.wait();

    console.log(transactionReceipt)    
}
```

One more question - can I verify my  contract on etherscan programmatically using ether.js or any other library.

I am very new to blockchain. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Since I am using the same abi and byte code every time, I wonder if it is a bad practice?*

It depends on your use case. For example each Uniswap pool contract has the same bytecode and same ABI, but they are multiple contracts - each with different variable values (e.g. addresses of the underlying tokens).

> *can I verify my contract on etherscan programmatically using ether.js or any other library*

Etherscan verification can be done through [their API](https://docs.etherscan.io/tutorials/verifying-contracts-programmatically) and there are wrappers of this API, for example a [Truffle plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-plugin-verify) or a [Hardhat plugin](https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan.html).

Comment: Yes I am going to use different values for each contracts. So that's a relief that now I can use my own dapp to deploy the contract.

Answer (score 1):

The same abi means contract has no change, so there is no need to redeploy again. If you just want to test some third libraries' function, just focus on building your web services.Such as use console.log() of javascript to output the button result. Hope it helps you

Comment: No the contract is same. but contractor parameters are different. Each contract connects with different ipfs link.